# Can we add extra font family in react-draft-wysiwyg editor

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

How to add extra custom font families in react-draft-wysiwyg draft editor currently I am
having fontfamily:{options:[Arial,Georgia,impact,tahoma,Times new Roman verdena]}
inside toolbar. Can we add extra custom fontfamilies?. If yes, can you please share me example or part of code.

Iam using the following editor version
draft-js: 0.10.x
immutable: 3.x, 4.x
react: 0.13.x, 0.14.x, ^15.0.0-0, 15.x.x
react-dom: 0.13.x, 0.14.x, ^15.0.0-0, 15.x.x

Comment: Have you figured this out?